# How to perform property binding with disabled property in angular?

Tags: angular

I was trying to print the names of only those cities for which the isDisabled value is true and the rest of the cities' values should be in a disabled state. But I am getting errors as shown.
The kind of output i want is:

**aaa , true**
bbb , false
ccc , false
ddd , false

the first one should be highlighted and rest shoud be disabled.

HTML file:

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of cities;let i=index">
<td [disabled]="isDisabled[i]">
    <tr>{{x.name}} , {{isDisabled[i]}}</tr>
</td>
```

.ts file:

```
cities = [{ name: "aaa" }, { name: "bbb" }, { name: "ccc" }, { name: "ddd" }];
isDisabled=[true, false, false, false]
```

> Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'td'

Comment: Indeed, `disabled` is not allowed on a `<td>` tag. It works for input/select etc... What do you mean by "diabled" then ? If you want a different text color, or bold, or anything, use CSS class instead: `[ngClass]="{'my-disabled': isDisabled[i]}"`.

Comment: by disabling I mean the text should appear but it will be disabled(meaning off-color). is my-disabled a variable in .ts file?

Comment: There is no magic here. The effect you want is well handled on `<input>` tags. But you're not using any `<input>` tag in your HTML, so you can't use it. You have to do it manually using a CSS class. So in my exemple, `my-disabled` is a custom CSS class, where you'll have to define the style you want to apply to it (so maybe a `color: gray`) in you CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some css code to solve your problem:

```
td.disabled {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Attaching this style to your code you can do the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of cities;let i=index">
<td [class.disabled]="isDisabled[i]">
    {{x.name}}, {{isDisabled[i]}}
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: yes the color is getting changed but it's not having the property of a disabled input field like not clickable or not allowing to enter. I mean the way disabled property works for an input field i want that. Can you help here?

Comment: You can add what ever css property to td.disabled css rule like I just added `cursor: not-allowed` to make it similar to disabled input.